# Call function after executing remote validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I have model with this property:

```
 [Required]
 [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]     
 [RegularExpression(@"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*@((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$",
        ErrorMessage = "Email has to be in correct format")]
 [Remote("UserRegistered", "User", ErrorMessage="This email is not registered")]
 public string Email { get; set; }
```

I want to show div in view after remote validation returns error, but not after any other validation returns error. Can i accomplish this in asp.net mvc 3 & unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Can you please post the answer/solution if you have got

Answer (score 0):

Oleg,

I've only ever used remote validation for validating unique usernames etc, so can't give any experienced advice on your particular issue, however, the following link 'may' help figure a strategy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx

perhaps more useful-> (hints at using the AdditionalFields property of Remote validation):

http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/07/19/using-asp-net-mvc-remote-validation-the-real-world-additionalfields/

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-remote-validation-for-multiple-fields-with-additionalfields-property

cheers..

Comment: thank you for answer. be honest, i also thought that additional fields may help, but when i google documentation, i learned that they help return other model properties into remote validation JsonReult method into controller. Its very userful, but it not resolves issue. Any way will learn you links. Thanks)

Comment: oleg - glad it helped you, keep me updated (and the answer updated :))